# Chart.js isn't being updated once an update call is made

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, chart.js

I have a small angular app that makes an api call based on a month/year from a drop down list in asp. It is meant for that api call to be made whenever year or month drop down lists are changed.

The first/original load works just fine. According to the debugger on any change I'm hitting the api on the change, and getting a return. The entire "card-widget"/ChartController div is disappearing (even with css properties commented out).

My ASP code:

```
<div id="card">
    <div>
        
    </div>
    <div id="card-widget" ng-app="ChartApp" ng-controller="ChartController" style="width:350px; height: 350px;">  
        <div>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="lstMonth" runat="server" ng-model="month" ng-change="updateChart()"></asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="lstYear" runat="server" ng-model="year" ng-change="updateChart()"></asp:DropDownList>
        </div>
        <div>
            <canvas id="Chart" height="350" width="350"></canvas>  
        </div>
    </div> 
    <div id="card-widget-fail" style="width: 350px; height: 100px;">
        <label>No chart</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

My Angular code:

```
var app = angular.module("ChartApp", []);
app.controller('ChartController', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.updateChart = function () { getChart() };
    var dataChart = document.getElementById("Chart").getContext('2d');
    var year = document.getElementById("<%=lstYear.ClientID %>");
    var month = document.getElementById("<%=lstMonth.ClientID %>");

    getChart();
    function getChart() {
    //api call to load chart data based off month.options[year.selectedIndex].text & year.options[year.selectedIndex].text
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason `getChart()` is not being called is because it's not present on the `$scope` element. Use `$scope.getChart = function() { ... }` instead. I recommend reading [this documentation page](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope), specifically the part "Scope as Data-Model".